# SASS use screen height to calculate remaining vh after a set height div

Tags: html, css, sass

So I have a div on my page that no matter the device size will be `209.53px`. I would like to have a calculation that can work out what percentage of the screen that this covers. That way I can set a map/image to fill the remaining portion of the screen.

I have tried to use height 80% ect but I just can't get it right, is there any way in `SASS`/`SCSS` to achieve this?

So I would go:

```
209.53/(SCREEN HEIGHT IN PIXELS) = PERCENTAGE COVERED
100 - PERCENTAGE COVERED = REMAINING VH

div{
    height: REMAINING VH;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't know which percentage of the vh represents a fixed height in css and by extension in sass/scss but you can leave the fixed height in 209.53 (I would recommend to round that value since css will do it anyway) and use css calc. Then your image would have the following height:

```
height: calc(100vh - 209.53px);
```

Other solution would be using absolute position and a margin top. Or better, use flex:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

   .fixed-height-element {
        flex: 0 0 209.53px;    
    }

   .image {
        flex: 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this a lot, I will try it Monday

Comment: Height css works perfectly. Didn't realise you could use different types of measurements like that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You set the `top` and `bottom` of your div element to get the remaining screen height:

```css
body {
  padding:0;margin:0;
}

#fixed {
  height: 209.53px;
  background-color:green;
  width:100%;
}

#remaining {
  position:absolute;
  top: 209.53px;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">this has height 209.53px</div>
<div id="remaining">this has height until screen bottom</div>
```

SASS is a precompiler therefor it can't help with calculations regarding the screen height.

Comment: Found another solution to pass it through from some javascript.

This didn't work for me

Comment: It is possible CSS only. Maybe my answer was to brief. I've added a snippet, you'll have to run it in full screen